# Trace stack-trace progression over time

Tags: c, debugging, trace

I'm working on a single threaded IOT application in C. Ultimately for an ARM microcontroller, but I have a desktop port. It's based on LWIP (Based on npcap) for the TCP/IP layer, then on top of that MbedTLS and HTTP.

I'm currently analyzing "hiccups" i.e. the communication is a bit jerky and there seems to be several 100-200ms waiting periods between the server and client communication. A more "traditional" network stacks would handle the entire request within 100ms, but my current implementation takes around a second.

I invested time for a desktop port to 1. prove the hiccups are due to the software stack and 2. have an easier time debugging. The behavior is consistent on ARM hardware and desktop port: both show the same waiting behavior at the exact same points in time.

Because it's single threaded the communication between the layers is tricky and because networking is involved debugging is tricky as well. As stepping through the functions results in timeouts, and pausing at the right moment didn't yield any useful findings.

Long story short, I'm looking for a way to analyze what is going on by tracing what function is getting called at what precise time. In other words I'd like to log or visualize stack-trace progression over time. Currently I'm on Windows using Visual Studio. But the project is CMake based and the code is portable C and I could switch to MinGW or Linux GCC.

My google searches all lead to very expensive hardware tracers like J-Trace. Are there any software tools or IDE features to do that on a desktop? Is there a term for that kind of debugging (beside tracing)?

Comment: *`"I'm working on a single threaded IOT application in C."`* Bad idea especially with TCP/IP. Learn freeRTOS

Comment: @gulpr sadly that was not my decision to make, it's a requirement based on legacy code I need to integrate with

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for a [Flame Graph](https://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html). One open source project that I've used in the past is [FlameGraph](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph) but there are many others as well.

Answer (score 1):

`J-Trace` is an overkill - it is used to trace more complicated issues ms are eternity for the uC.

If you have the SDO pin available and your debug probe supports SWO you can simply send short messages via debug port which will show you what function is called.

There is a tool called **tracelyzer** which is the tool you need.

Comment: I have SWO logging on the system, moreover the Desktop port would allow for even less invasive printf-style debugging.
However the TCP/IP stack is quite a big code base. Especially with the TLS crypto stuff on top. Manually adding print-statements in all of them seems like a tedious task. Are you aware of something that would automate it? Does tracelyzer do that?

Comment: @G.G most tcp/ip stacks have all logging inside  - simply those functions or macros are empty in the normal build